# How to sync a relational DB like Postgres updates/changes with Redis

Tags: postgresql, redis, synchronization

I've been struggling to understand how to use Redis to scale application services

I have data that don't change that often:

1. List of restaurants
2. Restaurant's menu with descriptions and prices, and so on

So I thought, ok, I will go and keep this data in Redis (like a cache). 
Example: A request goes to the service, service is querying the Redis, if the data is not in Redis, we're querying Postgres and setting the result in Redis. Next request will already get data only from Redis.

What is not clear how to do is:

- Once a change is done in PostgresDB, how will I sync it (preferably immediately) with Redis?
- Is there a way to use Redis for writes, not only for reads? For example order creation, or sending a message, etc. The idea is to first write it in Redis and than write the data into Relational Database (in my case Postgres)

Comment: have you found a solution for this?

Comment: Basically I was in a solution using Java.. So instead of Redis, I'm using Hazelcast now.. Also we've build an annotation that is set on the Controller level and once an endpoint has an annotation like that it will be cached